# C# versioned WebApi documentation using Swashbuckle / Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a C# WebApi with multiple versions that I would like to document using Swashbuckle/Swagger, using .net core 3.1. I have tried following the guides I could find around, but I seem to be missing something as swagger keeps displaying an empty list, like my project contained no API.

Here's the setup :

Startup.cs

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddApiVersioning(o => { });

            var apiExplorer = services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options => {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo()
                {
                    Title = "My API v1.0",
                    Version = "v1.0"
                });

                options.SwaggerDoc("v1.1", new OpenApiInfo()
                {
                    Title = "My API v1.1",
                    Version = "v1.1"
                });

                options.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo()
                {
                    Title = "My API v2.0",
                    Version = "v2.0"
                });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(0);
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "my API 1.0");
            });
        }
```

I have controllers defined like this :

```
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/weather/ByQuerySeparateClasses")]
    public class ByQuerySeparateClassesV1Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("read")]
        public WeatherResponse Get()
        {
            return new WeatherResponse() { Summary = "v1 by path, different controllers" };
        }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/weather/ByQuerySeparateClasses")]
    public class ByQuerySeparateClassesV2Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("read")]
        public WeatherResponse Get()
        {
            return new WeatherResponse() { Summary = "v2 by path, different controllers" };
        }
    }
```

When I run this API, here's the resulting JSON, an empty list like it's not seeing my APIs.

```
GET http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "My API v1.0",
    "version": "v1.0"
  },
  "paths": { },
  "components": { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or any hints how I could further diagnose what is going on?

A full example can be found here : https://github.com/mmgagnon/versioned-api-with-swagger

Comment: Do you have `app.UseMvc()`?

Comment: By the way looking at your link, you only need `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` NuGet package

Comment: @Krusty app.UseMvc() is not necessary, when I try to use it I get the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices(...).'". In any case, my APIs are working correctly, only the swagger documentation is problematic, so I really don't think the issue is there.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but UseMvc is required by Swagger to generate the API page. You can fix that exception by adding `.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; })`
It is confirmed here in the purple box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware

Comment: @Krusty I have been able to successfully generate the swagger API page without UseMvc - so long as I don't use API versions. But just to be sure, I tried adding UseMvc() to my example and it has not helped my original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
    {               
        o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        o.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
    });

    services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options => {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        //add this...
        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
        {
            if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
            {
                return false;
            }

            IEnumerable<ApiVersion> versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                .SelectMany(a => a.Versions);

            return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == docName);
        });
    
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "My API v1.0",
            Version = "v1.0"
        });

        options.SwaggerDoc("v1.1", new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "My API v1.1",
            Version = "v1.1"
        });

        options.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "My API v2.0",
            Version = "v2.0"
        });
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseApiVersioning();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSwagger(swagger => {
    });

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(0);
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "my API 1.0");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v2.0/swagger.json", "my API 2.0");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work quite a bit better! Just a few questions :

1) can you explain why that additional code is necessary? the documentation and examples I read online did not need that additional code, so why is it necessary in this case?

2) With your code, the "v1" endpoint returns some v2 APIs, and vice-versa the "v2" endpoint returns some "v1" APIs. This is most likely not intended?

Comment: The additional code is used to tell swagger what is the version by using `ApiVersionAttribute`.And why v1 endpoints returns some v2 apis,that is because in your ByPathSameClassController you add two `ApiVersionAttribute`.